# Portuguese encoding Ã£, Ãª, Ã§, Ã¡

Tags: python, encoding

I have this code:

```
with open('dataset.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    print(datafromAPI.decode("utf-8"),file=myfile)
```

which saves .csv file after decoding dataset from a data server through an API but the encoding is not displaying proper character. For instance, **ã shows Ã£, ê shows Ãª, ç shows Ã§, á shows Ã¡**, etc
I have tried to change starting from encoding of notepad++ and within my python code using **utf-8, latin-1, ISO 8859-1**, etc with no effect.

Comment: what does `print(type(dataFromAPI))` say?

Comment: and, if you can show it,  `print(repr(dataFromAPI[:10]))` (make sure it's nothing sensitive)

Comment: In case I'm not around for the response, this should help you or someone else get you the rest of the way: `"ã".encode('utf8').decode('iso-8859-1') = 'Ã£'` and `"ç".encode('utf8').decode('iso-8859-1') = 'Ã§'`

Comment: Does the API you got this data from actually provide data in UTF-8? And have you configured whatever program you're viewing the CSV in to interpret the CSV as UTF-8?

Comment: @jedwards, print(type(dataFromAPI)) says <class 'bytes'>

Comment: @jedwards, print(repr(dataFromAPI[:10])) says b'record_id,'

Comment: @jedwards, In case I'm not around for the response, this should help you or someone else get you the rest of the way: maybe this could solve but I am wondering that with this approach I am supposed to preview all possible accents á,é,í,ú,ó,ã,õ,à,ê,ç, etc you see...there are many possibilities so I thank that this approach is hard one.

Comment: @MGB.py no, sorry, what I meant was that properly encoded utf8 bytes, *decoded improperly* will result in the multi-characters strings you're seeing.

Comment: @user2357112, Does the API you got this data from actually provide data in UTF-8? **Yes, the server shows .csv dataset with names in correct way keeping accented words like á,é,í,ú,ó,ã,õ,à,ê,ç, etc** And have you configured whatever program you're viewing the CSV in to interpret the CSV as UTF-8? **I use Excel to confirm dataset display, so when I view .csv downloaded directly from API it shows nicely in Excel but with dataset got from my python through API Excel shows theses weird characters Ã£,Ãª,Ã§,Ã¡**

Answer (score 4):

I'll have to look into this further, but it's possible that `print` is doing something weird to your strings on the way to the file.

Since you know `datafromAPI` is a `bytes` object, consider trying the <s>three</s> two different approaches below:

**[`write` + text mode]**

```
with open('dataset.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write(datafromAPI.decode("utf-8"))
```

**[`write` + binary mode]**

```
with open('dataset.csv', "wb") as myfile:
    myfile.write(datafromAPI)
```

This last version will certainly work, provided you open it with an editor that supports the source encoding.

**Update:** *removed the version I wasn't sure would even work -- it will not.*

Comment: the last two options dont give erros of running but unfortunately the problem is kept not solved. The first option says this:     print(datafromAPI,file=myfile)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Yeah, I removed that, sorry about that -- the two options that remain use `myfile.write(...)`.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get your explanation. My problem is not solved yet.

Comment: The options have changed, have you tried both of the options that appear now?

Comment: If the last one doesn't work, the issue almost definitely is with your viewer/editor or code that exists outside of this snippet.  (In this snippet, Python is doing nothing regarding string encoding and working directly on bytes)

Comment: Can I have your email?

Answer (score 3):

As [commented by jedwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749834/portuguese-encoding-%c3%83%c2%a3-%c3%83%c2%aa-%c3%83-%c3%83#comment92424126_52749834) the encoding should be ISO 8859-1:

```
>>> "ã".encode('utf8').decode('iso-8859-1') 
'Ã£'
```

So you may want to try decoding the text with this encoding.

Comment: So, I am supposed to preview all possibles characters in this way. I think its hard way to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
open(filename, encoding='ISO-8859-15')
```

I've change **(encoding='utf-8')** to **(encoding='ISO-8859-15')**

If you want to save CSV on pandas try this **encoding='utf-8-sig'**

Comment: So easy, and worked like a charm. This answer should be waaay up higher.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility your file is fine but Notepad++ opens it using the wrong encoding.

Note there’s two groups of items in the Encoding menu:

- *Encode in UTF-8* will reinterpret the current data as UTF-8. You should see the text in the editor change as you use this item.
- *Convert to UTF-8* will convert the loaded data from the current encoding to UTF-8.

Load the file, and then check the current encoding in the status bar. If it does not display UTF-8 use “Encode in UTF-8” to view it as UTF-8.

The second possibility is that the server is incorrectly applying ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion to data which is already encoded as UTF-8. In that case, fix the server.

Comment: @MGB.py then it may be the second problem. Please follow jedwards’ advice and include the result of `print(repr(dataFromAPI[:10]))` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
>>>'â, ê, ô".encode('iso-8859-1').decode('iso-8859-1')

'â, ê, ô'

>>>'â, ê, ô".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')

'â, ê, ô'
```

You will notice that you should encode with `iso-8859-1`, because when going with utf-8, you'll get:

```
>>>"â, ê, ô".encode('utf-8').decode('iso-8859-1')

'Ã¢, Ãª, Ã´'
```

The third case is:

```
>>> "â, ê, ô".encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
```

But you'll get a UnicodeDecodeError.